# How would the following sentences would be transformed?

Tags: questions

1. Having Considered the question of expansion carefully the committee decided against the project.

**Begin** - Although _________________________________.

2. Someone had cut John's hair.

**Begin** - John _________________________________.

3. It looks as if Rahul has applied for the wrong job.

**Begin** - Rahul seems _______________________________________.

4. a) His uncle instructed him not to drive recklessly.

   b) He told him not to drink at that time.

**Join the above 2 sentences**

Answers of above sentences according to me -

1. Although the committee considered the question of expansion carefully, they decided against the project.
2. John had his hair cut by someone. **or** John's hair had been cut by someone.
3. Rahul seems to have applied for the wrong job.
4. His uncle told him not to drink at the time of driving to avoid driving recklessly.

So are the my answers correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Someone had cut John's hair.`, I would say—

> John's hair had been cut by someone.

or

> John had had his hair cut by someone.

The sentences in number 4 are a little odd, and it's not exactly clear what's being said, but I'd go for something like this:

> His uncle instructed him not to drive recklessly by drinking.

If "at this time" is important (even though it's not clear what time is meant—while driving? Who drinks when actually driving?), it might be better to stay non-committal:

> His uncle instructed him not to drive recklessly, and told him not to drink at that time.

or

> His uncle instructed him not to drive recklessly, telling him not to drink at that time.

Comment: 'His uncle instructed him not to drive recklessly by drinking.'
Um, 'by drinking' looks odd to me as the sentence mentioned in the question suggests time however this sentences is not referencing time.

Comment: Yes, although the original sentence is extremely vague (and not well written) so this is just a guess at the meaning. Agreed, though—"by drinking" is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Your first three are great.

However, four is awkward.

And alternative is as follows:

```
His uncle told him to avoid drinking before drive in case it made him reckless.
```

In an American English idiom:

```
His Uncle told him not to drink and drive in case it made him reckless.
```

Comment: At last sentence, "His Uncle to him", shouldn't it be "His uncle told him"? was it a typo?